# Flask, how to correctly upload CSV?

Tags: python, csv, flask

I'm creating an app where the client upload a CSV file and the server doesn't store it but only read it to perform tasks and return the content of the CSV as a JSON.

I followed some tutorials and posts and I came to this code:
Flask:

```
@app.route('/analyse_dataset', methods=['GET','POST'])
def analyse_dataset_route():
    print('/analyse_dataset called', file=sys.stderr)
    try:

        # check if the post request has the dataset part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            data = {'error': 'Dataset not in requested files'}
            return Response(data, status=400, mimetype='application/json')
        print('request.files : ' + str(request.files))
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']

        # no dataset
        if uploaded_file.filename == '':
            logger.debug('Dataset not found, returning to /')
            return redirect('/')

        # dataset ok
        if uploaded_file:
            print('uploaded_file ok', file=sys.stderr)
            filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
            #uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            uploaded_file.stream.seek(0) 
            myfile = uploaded_file.file 
            
            print('uploaded_file name: ' + filename, file=sys.stderr)
            
            dataframe = pd.read_csv(myfile)
            return Response(dumps(dataframe), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            data = {'error': 'Something went wrong...'}
            return Response(data, status=400, mimetype='application/json')
            
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('An error occurred while analysing dataset')
        logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
        print(e)
        data = {'error': 'An error occurred while analysing dataset'}
        return Response(data, status=400, mimetype='application/json')
```

client side:

```
onClickHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.selectedFile == null) {
            toast.error('No file selected')
        } else {
            const data = new FormData()
            data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
            let req = "http://localhost:5001/analyse_dataset"
            
            axios.post(req, data, {
                onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
                    this.setState({
                        loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total * 100),
                        loading: true
                    })
                },
            })
                .then(res => { // then print response status
                    console.log("file processed: " + res.data)
                    this.setState({
                        redirect: true,
                        jsondata: res.data
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => { // then print response status
                    console.log(err)
                    this.setState({
                        selectedFile: null,
                        loaded: 0,
                        loading: false
                    })
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        toast.error("Process failed, be sure to upload a correct file.")
                    }, 500)
                })
        }
    }
```

So there is this issue where it's "" working "" with a large CSV file but it isn't working with a smaller one and I can't figure out why. Also I'd like to return a JSON containing each line of the CSV to the client but for the moment it isn't working aswell.

Here is the error :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is likely failing on `myfile = uploaded_file.file`. Try changing the line to `myfile = uploaded_file.stream`.

If you are using Python 3, then pandas.read_csv requires text file/stream i.e. unicode. Convert the stream and it should work.

`myfile = io.StringIO(myfile.getvalue().decode())`

Once you have your `pd.DataFrame` object, you can use pd.DataFrame.to_json to convert your files. See the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

I am unsure as to exactly why larger files work.

Comment: Hi, but I'm not using Django , I use Flask

Comment: That... is very true! I'll get back to this, asap!